# Django default password_change doesn't work anymore?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm trying to user `django` built-in auth views to add `change password` function.

I create app named 'users' and configure `urls.py` like below :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout, password_change, password_change_done

from .views import SignUpView


app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^signup/$', SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    url(r'^login/$', login, name='login', kwargs={'template_name': 'users/login.html'}),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout', kwargs={'next_page': '/'}),
    url(
        r'^password_change/$',
        password_change,
        name='password_change',
        kwargs={
            'template_name': 'users/password_change_form.html',
            'current_app':'users'
        }
    ),
    url(
        r'^password_change/done$',
        password_change_done,
        name='password_change_done',
        kwargs={
            'template_name': 'users/password_change_done.html',
            'current_app':'users'
        }
    ),
]
```

And I also create `users/password_change_form.html`, `users/password_change_done.html`, too.

But it occurs error:

```
[20/Aug/2016 13:55:00] "GET /accounts/password_change/ HTTP/1.1" 500 106496
Internal Server Error: /accounts/password_change/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 149, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 49, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 308, in password_change
    post_change_redirect = reverse('password_change_done')
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 600, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/chacha_dabang/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 508, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_change_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Need your help. Thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have specified an `app_name` at the top of your URL config. This means that all the URLs you define are namespaced with that `app_name`. So the final name for your password change done URL is `users:password_change_done` and not `password_change_done`. That is why the reverse lookup fails.

You can fix this by passing a `post_change_redirect` kwarg to the `password_change` view:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

url(
    r'^password_change/$',
    password_change,
    name='password_change',
    kwargs={
        'template_name': 'users/password_change_form.html',
        'current_app':'users',
        'post_change_redirect': reverse_lazy('users:password_change_done')
    }
),
```

Note also that the `current_app` argument is [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_change) since Django 1.9:

> The `current_app` parameter is deprecated and will be removed in Django 2.0. Callers should set `request.current_app` instead.